# Partial Fraction Decomposition of $\frac{x^2}{(x-1)(x+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I am suppose to find the Partial Fraction Decomposition of
$$\dfrac{x^2}{(x-1)(x+1)^2}$$

My work so far:

$$\dfrac{x^2}{(x-1)(x+1)^2} = \dfrac{A}{x-1} + \dfrac{B}{x+1} + \dfrac{C}{(x+1)^2}$$

Thus,
$$ x^2 = A(x+1)^3 + B(x-1)(x+1)^2 + C(x+1)(x-1)$$

With x = 0 we get,
$$ 0 = A - B - C $$
I am not sure what to do after this, as plugging in the remaining factors (x = -1, 1) Does not help me find the unknown coefficients.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit. With $x = 1$, 
$$1 = A + 0B + 0C$$
$$A = 1$$

With $x = -1$
$$1 = 0A + 0B + 0C$$
$$1 = 0$$

Comment: I will try this again and update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your "thus" it must be

$$x^2=A(x+1)^2+B(x-1)(x+1)+C(x-1)$$

and not what you wrote there. Now substitute $\;x=1\;$ in both sides and get

$$1^2=A\cdot2^2\implies A=\frac14$$

and then substitute $\;x=-1\;$ and get ...etc.

Comment: @Toxicz, in fact an algebraic mistake and, imo, not that simple as all three summands in your right side are wrong...